# Difference between manual zip and powershell zip

Tags: powershell, zip

I want to zip multiple folders using PowerShell. When I do it via PowerShell its size is around 172 MB whereas when I manually zip it its around 175 MB and this is causing issue for me.

PowerShell script that I use:

```
$source = "C:\fso"
$destination = "C:\fso1\FSO_Backup.zip"
if (Test-Path $destination) {Remove-Item $destination}
Add-Type -Assembly "System.IO.Compression.Filesystem"
[IO.Compression.Zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($Source, $destination)
```

I tried using optimal/fast compression but of no use.

Can someone help me? I want to zip with same compression level that we use while doing it manually.

Comment: What issue does the size difference cause? I feel like you might be solving the wrong problem.

Comment: I am trying to upload the zip package to grid.. and the manual one is getting uploaded properly and the other one fails.

Comment: What is the failure? Is there an error? I cannot imagine that the size of the zip file would be the issue. Can you manually zip something else and upload it?

Comment: the interface is not so userfriendly, it just hungs when i try to upload the package.. all manually zipped packages are fine. I suppose there must be some differnece between manual zip and powershell zip

Comment: You have shown code used to create the archive file, but you say that the failure is during upload. How are you uploading the file?

Comment: What do you mean by "manually zip it"? Using Windows Explorer, WinZip, 7-zip, something else? The method you're using can take a compression level - e.g. `[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($source, $destination, [IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal, $true)` - so you could test the available options Optimal, vs Fastest, and there's an optional parameter after these to set the name encoding, that might make some size difference (maybe not 3Mb), but also maybe some compatibility difference.